# FIND_IN_SET problem

Tags: mysql

I have this MySql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_prods`
WHERE `id` IN ('58', '169', '166', '496', '24', '28')  
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`id`, '58, 169, 166, 496, 24, 28')
```

the result is weird:

```
24
28
166
169
496
58
```

I can't figure out how to return the exact order by my `FIND_IN_SET`

any ideas where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) instead of [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_prods`
WHERE `id` IN ('58', '169', '166', '496', '24', '28')  
ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, '58', '169', '166', '496', '24', '28')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not have spaces in

```
'58, 169, 166, 496, 24, 28'
```

Change it to

```
'58,169,166,496,24,28'
```